# When Starting multiple threads in a Queue, which one gets the first off the stack

Tags: python, multithreading

The python example gives anexample of how to wait for enqueued tasks to be completed but I am not sure how the order of retrieval is determined.  Here is the code:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

As I interpret it, this code starts whatever the `range` of threads is, the puts an however many `items` are in the `source` in the queue.

So if you start 20 threads, and put 30 items in the queue, it seems like you will have 20 worker threads all calling

```
while True:
    item = q.get()
    do_work(item)
```

So the first time an item is put on a queue, which of the 20 threads actually gets the item just put on the queue?

Comment: isn't that sort of the point ... one of them will get that item and the other 19 will block and your code should not need a particular one to get it?

Comment: Yeah, I am not exactly sure, it doesn't matter which one gets it, I was just curious how they make sure that multiple ones don't get it at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there isn't going to be a guaranteed order, only guaranteed mutual exclusion. Assuming you are using something like `queue.Queue` (Python 3), it uses synchronization primitives to ensure only one thread can `get()` an item at a time. But the order in which the threads get their chance will be affected by the vagaries of the OS scheduler - load, priorities, etc.